# How to refresh partial view in a .net-core mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have read multiple post on partial view but still can't figure out how it works.
I have a main page, within if I have a partial view, basically rendering an image.

I am "listening" a folder using FileSystemWatcher, when a new image arrives in it, depending on it's type it's doing some process and at the end of the process it should "refresh" the partial view.

in the main cshtml "fullPage.cshtml" I did this:

```
<div id="_PartialView">
    <h2><b>Images:</b></h2>
    @Html.Partial("PatialViewImage");
</div>
```

in the PartialViewImage.cshtml:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <img id="img_logo" alt="AIExampleResult" src=@ViewBag.CurrentImage style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:80%" />
   <h3>ImageProperties: @ViewBag.Resolution etc ...</h3>
</div>
```

in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> fullPage(int? id)
{
   if (id == null)
{
   return NotFound();
}

var patientdata = await _context.Patientdata
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdPatient == id);
if (patientdata == null)
 {
  return NotFound();
 }

//start to listen dragonfly folder
_watcher = new FolderWatcher();
_watcher.PathToWatch = _configuration["ConfigFolderListner:ImagesFolder"];
_watcher.patientdata = patientdata;
_watcher.Run();
_watcher.PropertyChanged += HandleNewJImage;
return View(patientdata);
}
```

so when a new image is detected it goes into (in the controller class) :

```
public void HandleNewJpeg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentImage = _watcher.LastImageProcessed;
    PartialView("PatialViewImage");
    return;
}
```

but it doesn't do anything.
when I debug:
it stops at the line PartialView("PartialViewImage"), but it doesn't seem to go into PartialViewImage.cshtml and the fullPage is not uploaded.

I tried to add in the fullPage.cshtml this javascript code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$("@ViewBag.CurrentImage").change(function refresh)
    function refresh() {
        $("#_PartialView").load("/Views/PatialViewImage");
    };

</script>
```

without success.
any idea how I could connect the FileSystemWatcher to my fullPage ?

**UPDATE**

in the full page I have add this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  CheckNewImages();
  var refreshId = window.setInterval(function () {
    CheckNewImages();
  }, 2000);
});

function CheckNewImages() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "@Url.Action("ReportPartialView")",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {id : @Model.IdPatient},
  success: function (data) {
   $('#_ReportPartialView').html(data);
   clearInterval(refreshId);
  },
  fail: function () {
   //do nothing
  }
});
```

to check time to time if I have a new image.
from the filesystemwatcher event, 
I try to update a database define like this:
in models:

```
public class PathImages
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string RawImage { get; set; }

  public string IAImage { get; set; }
}

public class TempContext : DbContext
{
 public TempContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
 { }

 public DbSet<PathImages> PathImages { get; set; }
}
```

in startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<SQLDATABASEContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDATABASE")));
services.AddDbContext<TempContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("name"));
```

and in the controller:

```
public void HandleNewJpeg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _context2.Add<PathImages>(new PathImages { RawImage = _context._watcher.LatestJPEGThumb, IAImage = "" });
    return;
}
```

but I get this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedExceptionHResult Cannot access a disposed object

I still don't get how I can pass data from `public void HandleNewJpeg(object sender, EventArgs e)` to a controller action.

Comment: You can't load the view directly. You need a controller action that returns that partial view. Then, you call that.

Comment: so I did this modification:
`public void HandleNewJpeg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentImage = _watcher.LastImageProcessed;
    RedirectToAction("PatialViewImage");
    return;
}`
and I added the action : 
`[ActionName("ReportPartialView")]
public ActionResult ReportPartialView()
{
ViewBag.CurrentImage = PatientImages[PatientImages.Count - 1];
return PartialView("ReportPartialView");
}`
but it doesn't go into public actionresult ReportPartialview. I don't know why

Comment: I tried `RedirectToAction("'PartialViewImage","Controller",null);` as well but it doesn't go into `[ActionName("PartialViewImage")] public ActionResult PartialViewImage() {}` either. I don't know why.

Comment: There is no way this could work as-is. Not with JavaScript, not with ASP.NET Core. You have to understand that ASP.NET Core is a state-less web server, nothing done by `HandleNewJpeg` will affect anything nor anyone as-is. Questions: 1) are your users authenticated? 2) who cares about the new image, the user that uploaded them, everyone...?

Comment: the user doesn't updload them. a device add them time to time on the server side. when it arrives I have to update the web page.

Comment: But the webpage for *who*? Is there one user? Multiple users?

Comment: multiple users (they do not take the image, they have to be notified a new one arrived). I understood that the server can't update the web page that's why I made the javascript running a controller action every x secondes.

Comment: Ok. This is way too broad, but: 1) you'd have to use sessions so you know which users are in the system, store those somewhere, possibly in a Singleton service, 2) store the images received somewhere, link them to the users so you know who has read it so you can delete it, 3) add a javascript timer so that every unit of time you want calls a controller action that checks if there is any image for that user and, if so, update the UI. Another option would be to use ASP.NET Core SignalR, if you can use WebSockets

Comment: I have added : `services.AddSession();` and `app.UseSession();` in the startup.cs, but I haven't get how to use them

Comment: isn't it possible to do something with IHostService/Background class ? puting an equivalent of the FileSystemWatcher as IHostService ?

Comment: is it possible to access a dbcontext from ihostservice background task? I do a background task which look for new files, when a new one is detected can the Ihostservice add it to the dbcontext ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<partial>` tag helper,`<div id="imageChanged"> <partial name="Partial/PatialViewImage" model="new ViewModel() { ImSrc = Model.ImSrc}" /> </div>`. If you want refresh the page you need to have a controller action that will returns partial view.

User JQuery with event or without event for example

```
 (function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: ROOT + 'Home/GetImage',
            data: { imgId : @Model.ImgId },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                     $('#imageChanged').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (res) {
                    }})
    })();
```

Comment: it doesn't accept "new ViewModel()" the type or namespace viewmodel is missing.
Moreovever, I don't get how to call the ajax function from this function?
`public void HandleNewJpeg(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentImage = _watcher.LastImageProcessed;
    PartialView("PatialViewImage");
    return;
}`

Comment: about, new ViewModel, the image path is not contained in the model used in the view, that's why I tried to use ViewBag to pass it. it should not as it is common to all entry of the sql table.

Comment: and using the tag partial: The partial view 'PartialViewImage.cshtml' was not found even if it has been searched at the good place.

Comment: Hi @p.deman, it just an example. Event handler can't return an view what your are trying, you need to have a controller action that will return partial view.

Comment: I added a controler action: `[ActionName("PartialViewImage")] public ActionResult PartialViewImage() {}` in my controller. and in function handling the event public void HandleNewJpeg(object sender, EventArgs e) { ViewBag.CurrentImage = _watcher.LastImageProcessed; RedirectToAction("'PartialViewImage","Controller",null);} but it doesn't go into the Controller action, I don't know why.

Comment: From event handler you can not redirect to any view. 
        private void HandleNewJImage(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
           // TODO: This event can not return your view.
        }

        public IActionResult PartialViewImage()
        {
//TODO: getting image logic here
            return PartialView("Your-View-Name");
        } call PartialViewImage controller action using any jQuery event.

Comment: so I did this in fullPage.cshtml:
`$(document).ready(function () {
            CheckNewImages();
            var refreshId = window.setInterval(function () {
                CheckNewImages();
            }, 2000);
        });`

Comment: and and `function CheckNewImages() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("PartialViewImage")",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                // data: json,
                success: function (data) {
                        $('#imageChanged').html(data);
                        clearInterval(refreshId);
                },
                fail: function () {
                    //do nothing
                }
            });
    }`

Comment: ok it seems to work, but rendering the partial reset all properties of my controller, it kills my fileeventlistener.

Comment: after each PartialView it go into my controller constructor

Comment: how can I prevent to lose all properties initiate in the main view and methodes running when updating the partial view?

Comment: You can hidden your all properties initiate in the main view using <input type="hidden"> html tag helper or you can have jQuery click or others event for having image. for example - $('#imageId').clieck(here your Ajax function)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191904/discussion-between-p-deman-and-mofaggol-hoshen).